# PHPStormの設定について

Tags: phpstorm

いつもお世話になっています。

PHPStormの導入を考えていたのですが、最初から躓いてしまっています。
Laravelプロジェクトを作りたかったので、Laravel Pluginを導入し、以下の手順を踏んだのですが、先に進むことが出来ません。
ぐぐって調べてみたのですが、希望の解決方法に行き当たらなかったので、どなたかご享受願えませんでしょうか？

・New Project > Comporser Project を選択
・Download comporser.phar from getcomporser.orgを選択
・Filter packagesに「laravel/laravel」を入力、Available packagesに表示された「laravel/laravel」を選択すると、「There is no default interpreter in default settings」と赤いエラー文字が表示されて先に進めない
・Use existing comporser.pharでPC内にあるcomporser.pharを選択しても同様

環境はWindows10
Vagrant、CentOS7、PHP7となっています。

英語があまり得意ではないため、読み解けていないだけだと思うのですが……。
お手数お掛け致しますが、宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: interpreterはphpコマンドのことでしょうから、（Composerの実行に必要な）PHPのインストール先をPHPStormが認識していないのではないでしょうか。PHPStormの設定でその辺りを指定する箇所がありそうですが…ところでWindows側にもPHPはインストールされているのですよね？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！質問後も色々触ってみて、interpreter辺りも何となく理解はしたのですが、VagrantからPHP先をRemoteで取得するとまた別のエラー出たりとなかなか進めないでいます。もう少し設定触ってみます。ありがとうございました。PHPインストール等々は出来ています。